# Is there a way of silencing bounty notifications?

Tags: support, bounties, notifications

Every time I post a bounty, StackExchange starts annoying me with useless notifications: "Your bounty ends in 3 days", "Your bounty ends in 1 day", "Your bounty is over", etc. Is there a way of turning them off somehow?

A quick Google search failed to turn up anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

In [your profile preferences](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/9009) you can disable email notifications altogether:

[image: Email preferences.]

Comment: I suspect he's not talking about email notifications, but the little red notifications at the top of the page.  Although you do get emails too I guess.